# Changing Color Darkness Programmatically in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, colors, uikit, uicolor

I have a image that is pure white. It is the white at the center of the [Mac color wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIZhe.png). I want to increase the darkness of the white programmatically. (Non programmatically would be to [slide the slider down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDpVr.png))

I need a darker white, then darker than that, etc. How would I achieve this with code?

Comment: Is the image just all white? If so, why use an image at all instead of just a view with a white background color, which you can easily change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when dealing with colors programmatically, I prefer to use Hue, Saturation, and Brightness. It's much easier to progress colors using increments of each parameter.

- **Hue** is a float representing the percentage of 360 degrees on the color wheel (e.g. 0 to 1).
- **Saturation** represents the intensity of that color and is a a float between 0 and 1, again.
- **Brightness** is what you are trying to modify and will take you from pure white, to pure black. Again, a float between 0 and 1.

UIColor provides a factory method

```
- (UIColor *)initWithHue:(CGFloat)hue saturation:(CGFloat)saturation brightness:(CGFloat)brightness alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

[Here's a link to the UIColor class reference and the above method.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:)